# How to create a new label when a button is clicked in javafx and scenebuilder?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm very new to javafx and scenebuilder.
I was trying to create a new label when a button is clicked. Following is the method for the button to create a label:

```
@FXML 
public void enterTextMouse(MouseEvent e){
    Label lbl1 = new Label(txtCmd.getText());
}
```

But it doesn't work. :(
Is it because I didn't create lbl1 in my fxml?
Is it possible to create a label in my java code without creating in fxml?
Please help me!

Comment: What is not working? Any exception or stacktrace? What is `txtCmd`?

Comment: txtCmd is the text field. What I want to do is that the user types in the text field (txtCmd) and clicks the button. And then a new label lbl1 will be created and displayed.

Comment: Ok, and what exactly is not working? Are there any errors, exceptions, stacktrace?

Comment: There is no error. But the label does not appear when I click the button.

Comment: Well that may be the case, because you are not adding it anywhere to the GUI. You are just creating it..

Comment: So how should I create the labels if I want to read lines from a file and display each line using a label on GUI? Since I might not know how many lines in the file, I will not know how many labels to create in GUI. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: This sounds not like what you orginally asked, but in that case I would suggest the `ListView` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Let's make one pane and set fx:id(paneLoadLabel) in scenebuilder
2. Write this in controller

`@FXML
private Pane panelLoadLabel;`

```
@FXML 
public void enterTextMouse(MouseEvent e){
    Label lbl1 = new Label(txtCmd.getText());
    paneLoadLabel.getChildren().add(lbl1);
}
```

Comment: When the label is created, how can I specify the position?